# Storing value from DynamoDB as integer in React-Native app

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to save a user's progress by storing a value in a DynamoDB. Storing the value is no big deal, retrieving this value to use in my app, however is proving challenging.

Using `dynamoDBWrapper.getItem(params)` where params looks like

```
const params = {
        Key: {
            "userId": {
                S: "2"
            }
        },
        TableName: "Users",
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL"
    };
```

returns a promise. Unfortunately, I can't store the value of this promise to a variable. How can I utilize the value in this table in my project?

EDIT:
Calling this function:

```
dynamoDBWrapper.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.error(err.message);
        else {
            result = data.Item;
            console.log("Else")
        }
    });
```

does not ever lead to console output. I'm 100% sure that I'm calling keys that exist in the database too.

Answer (score 0):

1. It does not return a promise. It returns an [asynchronous request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html) but this is not what you're looking for.
2. Your `params` is missing the `Key` attribute. It shouldn't have an `Item` attribute either. (See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html))
3. Using the callback, you can get the returned item using the `data` object as in `data.Item`. For example:

   ```
   const params = {
     TableName: "Music",
     Key: {
      "Artist": {
        S: "No One You Know"
       },
      "SongTitle": {
        S: "Call Me Today"
       }
     },
     ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL"

   };

   dynamoDBWrapper.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err.message)
     } else {
       const progress = data.Item;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm not convinced that the wrapper I'm using (DynamoDBWrapper) calls the callback function, because even when the .putItem call adds to the database, there is no console log. I just can't seem to get this to work. I've updated my code in my question.